# How do I configure Jackson ObjectMapper to deserialize all fields of type Foo into instances of SubclassOfFoo?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, subclass

I'm deserializing a large json value. Deeply nested within that value is a json object like the following:

```
{
  "fieldOne": "valueOne",
  "fieldTwo": {
    "innerField": "innerValue"
  }
}
```

I'm using the Jackson `ObjectMapper` to deserialize the large json value into a 3rd party class. Deeply nested within that 3rd party class is another 3rd party class:

```java
public class DeepThirdPartyClass {
    public String fieldOne;
}
```

which unfortunately is missing the `fieldTwo` property. I can create my own class which adds the missing field:

```java
public class MyClass extends DeepThirdPartyClass {
    public MySubObject fieldTwo;
}
```

How do I configure jackson so that whenever it attempts to deserialize a value to `DeepThirdPartyClass`, it deserializes to `MyClass` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked @olga-khylkouskaya's solution to fit my problem:

```java
@Test
public void newDeserializer() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("DeepThirdPartyClass subclass override", new Version(1, 0, 0, "FINAL", "com.example", "deep-third-party-class-override"));
    module.addDeserializer(DeepThirdPartyClass.class, new JsonDeserializer<DeepThirdPartyClass>() {
        @Override
        public DeepThirdPartyClass deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            return p.readValueAs(MyClass.class);
        }
    });
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"middle\": {\n" +
            "    \"fieldOne\": \"valueOne\",\n" +
            "    \"fieldTwo\": {\n" +
            "      \"fieldThree\": \"valueThree\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}\n";

    ThirdPartyClass thirdPartyClass = objectMapper.readValue(json, ThirdPartyClass.class);
}

public class ThirdPartyClass {
    public DeepThirdPartyClass middle;
}

public class InnerClass {
    public String fieldThree;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement when I have to filter any not allowed characters in all String values.
To create Object Mapper:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        super();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("HTML XSS Serializer", new Version(1, 0, 0, "FINAL", "com.crowdoptic", "web"));
        module.addSerializer(String.class, new JsonHtmlXssSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(String.class, new JsonHtmlXssDeserializer());

        this.registerModule(module);
    }
}

public class JsonHtmlXssDeserializer extends StdScalarDeserializer<String> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(JsonHtmlXssDeserializer.class);

    public JsonHtmlXssDeserializer() { super(String.class); }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String value = StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        LOG.trace("in deserialize for value: " + value);
        String encodedValue = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(value);
        return encodedValue;
    }
    @Override
    public String deserializeWithType(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, TypeDeserializer typeDeserializer) throws IOException {
        return StringDeserializer.instance.deserializeWithType(jp, ctxt, typeDeserializer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCachable() { return StringDeserializer.instance.isCachable(); }
}
```

In your case you can register your class deserializer, call super method of the object deserializer. Then instead of returning DeepThirdPartyClass, create object of MyClass, set field one from DeepThirdPartyClass and add second field. See StringDeserializer and others for implementation details and available properties.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but I still don't see how to adapt your solution to my problem. You say that I should call the super method of the object deserializer, but what super class should I be using? I can't use StdScalarDeserializer, as you do, because the value for fieldTwo is never a scalar.

Comment: ok, I think I found something that works. Let me know if you have any ideas for simplifying it.